# How to obtain jQuery UI Sortable item positions?

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 jQuery UI Sortable lists. Codes are as follow:

```
<div class="chapter_container">
  <p>Available Chapters</p>
  <ul id="sortable_available">
    <li id="t1">Title 1</li>
    <li id="t2">Title 2</li>
    <li id="t3">Title 3</li>
    <li id="t4">Title 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="chapter_container">
  <p>Selected Chapters</p>
  <ul id="sortable_selected">
  </ul>
</div>
```

For the JS, I use:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#sortable_available, #sortable_selected").sortable({
    connectWith: ".chapter_container ul"
  });
  jQuery("#sortable_selected").on("sortstop", function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.position);
  });
  jQuery("#sortable_available, #sortable_selected").disableSelection();
});
```

I can only obtain the position of item moved via `sortstop` event. How can I obtain the orders of items in both lists?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/rktqv5es/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the `refreshPositions` method? If you make a call to this method, you can query the children from the returned object.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/rktqv5es/3/)

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#sortable_available, #sortable_selected").sortable({
    connectWith: ".chapter_container ul"
  });

  jQuery("#sortable_available").on("sortstop", function(event, ui) {
    //Clear the existing content.
    jQuery('#debug').html('');

    //Call refreshPositions and store the children in a local variable.
    var items = jQuery(this).sortable("refreshPositions").children();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      //I'm using javascript to get the required values, but you can use jQuery if you so desire.
      jQuery('#debug').html(jQuery('#debug').html() + items[i].innerHTML + ', Top: ' + items[i].offsetTop + ', Left: ' + items[i].offsetLeft + '<br/>');
    }
  });

  jQuery("#sortable_available, #sortable_selected").disableSelection();
});
```

Moving the second item to the first position will output the following:

> Title 2, Top: 115 Left: 18
>
> Title 1, Top: 152 Left: 18
>
> Title 3, Top: 189 Left: 18
>
> Title 4, Top: 227 Left: 18

`$(".selector").sortable("refreshPositions").children();` will return an array.

Comment: Nice. Almost working perfectly. And here is the documentation of [refreshPositions event](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refreshPositions)